# How can I refresh the .env file in Laravel if there's no root access?

Tags: php, laravel

I am on a shared hosting. I am not the developer but I just changed a value in the .env file but the change is not reflecting on the main site. I even tried by opening http://siteurl.com/clear-cache(it says cache cleared) but it didn't work. How can I refresh it without root access? I can hardcode the value for now as a temporary hack but I want to make it work via the .env file.

Comment: try deleting the cache folder under bootstrap folder.

Comment: `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: @Ben i dont have command line access.

Answer (score 0):

In order to clear cache of config in **Laravel 5**

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan optimize
```

with those command you will clear all cache and go on